# Android Listview using Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, listview

Iam building sample android app . Initially am displaying list with some cities.by clicking on any one of  the city it will display map regarding to that city.

now am suffering with how to connect selected city from list with googlemap.any idea please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You simply make the list of city objects. Each object will contain the name of the city and the location (latitude, longitude). When you click an item, go to a map activity passing the location in the Intent object. In the map activity you'll parse the location and tell the map to go to that point.

Comment: yeah you are right but am unable to getting latitude and logitude?

Comment: If you haven't already done so, your list adapter should extends ArrayList<City>. The object City should contain name, latitude, longitude. When an item is clicked, you get the city object from the onItemClicked of the ListView. This method gives you the item position in the array and you get City item = cities.get(position);. Then you make an intent and put in it's bundle the latitude and longitude this way: Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyMapActivity.class); intent.putExtra("latitude", item.getLatitude()); intent.putExtra("longitude", item.getLongitude());startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, U have, for example database(or local data structure in your list activity) with cities and corresponding coordinates. Then, in `onListItemClick()` you create new intent and insert to it's extras necessary data (title, coordinates or primary key of the row in db table). Start new activity extended MapActivity with this intent, take `mMapController = mMapView.getController();` and animate to `mMapController.animateTo(new GeoPoint((int)yourLatitudeE6,(int)yourLongitudeE6))`, where yourLatitudeE6 and yourLongitudeE6 - extras from intent

Comment: how will i take city name on that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should  have lat and long of city .So you can send that lat and long to mapview through bundle and populate map of that city. In this link you can get complete tutorial for mapview . http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html